# (Sentry) source maps are not sent to the project by sentry-cli

Tags: angular, sentry

#### Environment

package.json

```
"@sentry/angular": "6.18.2",
"@sentry/cli": "2.5.2",
"@sentry/tracing": "6.18.2",
```

.sentryclirc

```
[auth]
token=74cc88aha9414f36a8f3943550a1....
[defaults]
url = https://sentry.my-page.co.uk/
project=my-app
org=sentry
```

mian.ts

```
Sentry.init({
  release: "0.0.1",
  dsn: environment.sentry_dsn,
```

#### Steps to Reproduce

- run `sentry-cli releases new 0.0.1`
- run `sentry-cli releases files  0.0.1 upload-sourcemaps ./dist`

```
> ~/default~account-account-module~bill-bill-module~credit-topup-credit-topup-module~dashboard-dashboard~23518288-es2015.js> ~/default~account-account-module~bill-bill-module~credit-topup-credit-topup-module~dashboard-dashboard~23518288-es2015.js
> Rewriting completed in 1.718s
> Adding source map references
> Bundling files for upload... ~/network-network-module-es5.js.map
> Bundling completed in 4.08s
> Optimizing completed in 0.13s
> Uploading completed in 78.408s
> Uploaded release files to Sentry
> Processing completed in 0.12s
> File upload complete (processing pending on server)
> Organization: sentry
> Project: my-app
> Release: 0.0.1
> Dist: None

Source Map Upload Report
  Scripts
    ~/account-account-module-es2015.js
    ~/account-account-module-es5.js
...
...
...
    ~/vendor-es2015.js
    ~/vendor-es5.js
  Minified Scripts
    ~/alerts-alerts-module-es2015.js (sourcemap at alerts-alerts-module-es2015.js.map)
    ~/dashboard-dashboard-module-es2015.js (sourcemap at dashboard-dashboard-module-es2015.js.map)
...
...
...
    ~/runtime-es5.js (sourcemap at runtime-es5.js.map)
    ~/statement-statement-module-es2015.js (sourcemap at statement-statement-module-es2015.js.map)
  Source Maps
    ~/account-account-module-es2015.js.map
...
...
...
    ~/vendor-es2015.js.map
    ~/vendor-es5.js.map
```

#### Expected Result

I should see new files .js, js.map in Source maps tab in my project

#### Actual Result

The Source maps tab in my project is blank
there are no files

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely an issue with self-hosted instance not preserving your files. See https://github.com/getsentry/self-hosted/issues/1579#issuecomment-1205088691 and look for related issues.